# Every harmonic funcion defined on an open ball as a conjugate

Tags: real-analysis, integration, harmonic-functions

Let $B_r(x_0,y_0) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be the open ball of radius $r>0$ centered at $(x_0,y_0)$, I want to prove that if $u:B_r(x_0,y_0) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is harmonic, that is, a $C^2$ function that satisfies $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$, then there exist a $C^2$ function $v$ such that
$$
u_x=v_y \textrm{ and } -u_y=v_x
$$
This is why I tried:
From the first equation, we have that if such a $v$ exist, then
$$
v(x,y)=\int_{y_0}^{y}{u_x(x,t)dt}+g_{1}(x)
$$
Similarly, we have by the second equation that
$$
v(x,y)=-\int_{x_0}^{x}{u_y(s,y)ds}+g_2(y)
$$
By setting the two equations equal to each other we get that
$$
g_2(y)=\int_{y_0}^{y}{u_x(x,t)dt}+\int_{x_0}^{x}{u_y(s,y)ds}+g_1(x)
$$
Therefore,
$$
0=u_y(x,y_0)+g_1'(x)
$$
Which entails that
$$
g_1(x)=-\int_{x_0}^{x}{u_y(s,y_0)ds}+C
$$
For some constant $C$, and thus
$$
v(x,y)=\int_{y_0}^{y}{u_x(x,t)dt}-\int_{x_0}^{x}{u_y(s,y_0)ds}+C
$$
This function $v$ would satisfy by construction what we want. My question is: **where did we use that $u$ is defined on a ball?** It is of my understanding that we can't just take any domain, but where does this proof break down if we change the region? I don't see it. I don't know anything about complex analysis, so I would appreciate an explanation in terms of real analysis.

Any help?

In advance thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the integrals you used in the proof may not exist if the domain is not  a convex set. For example, $\int_{y_0}^{y}{u_x(x,t)dt}$ may not be defined because the fact that $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x,y)$ are in the domain does not imply that $(x,t)$ is in the domain for $t$ between $y_0$ and $y$.

Comment: Oh, you're right! I didn't notice that :( . Thank you very much!